# Dynamically create tables and copy data from MySQL to a SQL Server Database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, dynamic-tables

I am able to create a table manually in SQL Server by checking columns from MySQl table. And then able to move data from MySQL to SQL Server table.

Example: MySQL table = Employee

```
Describe Employee;
```

**Output**

```
Field,   Type,       Null,  Key, Default, Extra
EmpId   int(10)       NO     PRI    0
Name    varchar(100)  YES       
Age     int(10) YES                 18
EmailId  varchar(100) NO
```

Using this I am creating same table in SQL Server

```
Drop table MsSQLdb..Employee;
CREATE TABLE Employee (
    EmpId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 0,
    Name varchar(100),
    Age int de,
    Name varchar(100)  NOT NULL DEFAULT  18
);
```

***Now using OpenQuery to copy the data from MySQL to SQL Server :***

```
select EmpId,Name,Age,EmailId into MsSQLdb..Employee
from
OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'SELECT EmpId,Name,Age,EmailId  FROM mySQL_db.Employee')
```

But, daily my mySQL_db.Employee table gets more columns or less. So daily I need to manually Map this columns in the above queries to redo the task. Is there any dynamic way for this task?

I have around 40-tables and each table have around 30+ columns. so looking for any a dynamic way.

Comment: How do you know what column is added or being removed ?

Comment: How on Earth do you get different number of columns on a daily basis in a production system? What if they use a data type in mysql that you cannot (json) or should not (enum) directly import into ms sql server?

Comment: @Shadow, that's already my problem with prod tables here..Its still in slow development for a year now. so posted this question for help

Answer (score 0):

You can go for `SELECT * INTO` for loading data into tables. [More on SELECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

I assume that you are fine for `DROP` & `RECREATE` and simple scenario of loading data. You might not get right datatype as datatype is automatically decided by SQL Server based on initial set of rows.

```
DROP TABLE dbo.Employee;
SELECT * INTO dbo.Employee 
from
OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'SELECT * FROM mySQL_db.Employee')
```

> Indexes, constraints, and triggers defined in the source table are not
>   transferred to the new table, nor can they be specified in the
>   SELECT...INTO statement. If these objects are required, you can create
>   them after executing the SELECT...INTO statement.